# Cannot get response header with the same key name (*http.Header)

Tags: go

Let's say I have 2 response headers with the same name "Set-Cookie"

The .Get method can only get the first value

In the document it said:
`To access multiple values of a key, or to use non-canonical keys, access the map directly.`

```golang
fmt.Println(headers.Get("Set-Cookie"))
// -> Can only get the first one
```

However when read the map

```golang
for key,value := range headers {
  fmt.Println(key, value)
}
// -> cannot range over headers (type *http.Header)
```

Currently I'm not sure the right way to read this data.

Comment: `headers` is a slice of strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`http.Header` is already a `map[string][]string` so there should be no need to pass the address of it around. If you somehow passed `&request.Header`, then you should pass it directly instead, without taking the address. If you have to pass the address for some reason, range over `*headers` instead of `headers`:

```
for key,value := range *headers {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Values` instead of `Get`. [Values](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Header.Values) returns all values associated with the given key.

Comment: this is the only right answer lol